# I am trying to select current date from the depart calendar in Make My trip but unable to located the web element through selenium and java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to click on departure button but it is showing error as the element is not clickable.And can anyone please suggest a way to select the current date without hardcoding.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\rutsahoo\\Documents\\chromedriver.exe" );
WebDriver driver; 
        
String strURL="https://www.makemytrip.com/";
driver= new ChromeDriver();//created object of chrome driver  
        
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(strURL);
Thread.sleep(4000);
        
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class=\"lbl_input latoBold appendBottom10\"])[1]")).click();
        
Thread.sleep(4000);
        
driver.close();
```

Comment: Please share your code including output and URL or html source code.

Comment: @pburgr : Added code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xpath` you are using isn't highlighting any element in the DOM. First click on the `Departure` element and then select from the `calendar`.

```
Imports required for Explicit Waits:
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/flights");
        
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
Actions actions1 = new Actions(driver);
        
// Close the login pop-up 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//p[contains(@class,'login__earn')]")));
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Login or Create Account']"));
actions1.moveToElement(login).click().perform();
        
//  Close the language pop-up
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='langCardClose']"))).click();

// Departure Element        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@for='departure']"))).click();
// Select the date
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label='Wed Oct 27 2021']"))).click();
```

Comment: I added the code to click on departure but it is showing exception as Element Click intercepted exception .

Comment: @Anjali - Thats because of the language pop-up. Close the pop-ups and try. Have reupdated the answer for the same.

Comment: Thanks for the help the code works now.